# soap UI to generate a mock service and test client

Tags: soapui

i am trying to do a soap with ws security.
How do I use soap UI to generate  a mock service and then test client. How much control can I have on the security headers. Do I need to manually add security details or does it automatically do it from the wsdl.. Any links or tutotials will be very helpful

This is just to generate a soap xml

```
    soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mhs="http://org/emedny/mhs/" xmlns:urn="urn:hl7-org:v3">
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-e00c8062-83d2-4f04-88fc-996218e7bb3d">MIICeDCC....(eMedNY signed user MLS cert).......</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-c0cc2cd4-cb77-4fa5-abfa-bd485afd1685">MIIDFj.....( eMedNY MLS web-service end-point public cert)........</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-970e9a80-00cc-4c86-8ec4-3ba16e029a5b">
<wsse:Username>....your_username.....</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">.....your_plaintext_password....</wsse:Password>
<wsse:Nonce>KNyu6MsXCkTg4DDyvwvEiw==</wsse:Nonce>
<wsu:Created>2010-09-15T18:00:30Z</wsu:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
<xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
<wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-c0cc2cd4-cb77-4fa5-abfa-bd485afd1685" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
</wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
</KeyInfo>
<xenc:CipherData>
<xenc:CipherValue>gpBAWt91pdwhKva............</xenc:CipherValue>
</xenc:CipherData>
<xenc:ReferenceList>
<xenc:DataReference URI="#Enc-0641b860-b16d-4941-91c0-d60bece67794"/>
</xenc:ReferenceList>
</xenc:EncryptedKey>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
SAMP L E R EQUE ST W I T H WS S E CURI T Y
eMedNY Meds History Service User Guide Page 13 of 48 February 16, 2012
Version 1.1
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<Reference URI="#Id-f10674fd-b999-47c9-9568-c11fa5e5405b">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<DigestValue>wRUq.........</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>tBSsaZi........</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
<wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-e00c8062-83d2-4f04-88fc-996218e7bb3d" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
</wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may use this tutorial: [Applying WS-Security](http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/applying-ws-security.html). Basically:

1. create a new SoapUI project
2. when creating select check box to generate mock service
3. double click on project in the tree
4. configure WSS settings in "WS-Security Configurations" tab
5. select WSS configuration for the mock service (beware - it is not in a pop-up but in a properties table in bottom left of the screen - see [How to apply WSS to mocked response in SoapUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772579/how-to-apply-wss-to-mocked-response-in-soapui/19232941)

You have quite fine grained control over configuration details (used encryption and signature algorithms, encrypting only parts of messages aso.) but you do not control raw XML tags for encryption.