# How to apply WSS to mocked response in SoapUI?

Tags: encryption, soapui, ws-security

I have a SoapUI Mock Service. I would like it to use WS-Security.

I configured the project WS-Security Configurations, both Outgoing and Incoming.

I use a Test Suite to send a request and it is properly processed with Timestamp, Signature and Encrypt WSS Entries. But the response from the Mock Service is a plain text fault:

```
Missing operation for soapAction [] and body element 
[{http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#}EncryptedData] with SOAP Version [SOAP 1.1]
```

From this message I guess that the mock service did not recognize encryption HTML elements. Am I right?

Is there a way to encrypt SoapUI mock service responses using WS-Security?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible. The options can be found after clicking on the mock service *in the bottom left part of the screen* (unlike all other configuration options that are available in popups). There you can choose outgoing and incoming security configuration set from a dropdown.

It is hidden so well that I ran into the problem twice within three months, performed a research and found my own unanswered question in StackOverflow before a friend showed me the solution.

So I post the answer should anyone need that.